# Converting import statements to link tags in inline style tags

Tags: css, import

I am trying to write a script which converts `@import` statements to
`<link>` tags, and I have two questions:

1. Can an `@import` statement and other style statements co-exist inside
   a `<style>` tag? e.g.:

   ```html
   <style type="text/css">
       @import url(http://www.example.com/style.css);
       body {
           background: #FFF;
       }
       ..NUI_ContentFrameHeader_l {
           clear: both;
           height: 50px;
           margin: 0;
           color: black;
           background: url(/vpn/images/NUI_box_l.png) no-repeat left top;
           border: solid 0px #BBC6D6;
           overflow: hidden;
           letter-spacing: 0;
           padding: 0 0 0 15px;
       }
   </style>
   ```
2. If there are more than one `@import` statements in the beginning of a `<style>` tag and this is not a scoped style tag, can we convert `@import` statements to `<link>` statements and move them just above the `<style>` tag? like:

   ```html
   <style type="text/css">
       @import url(http://www.example.com/style1.css);
       @import url(http://www.example.com/style2.css)
       body {
           background: #FFF;
       }
       ..NUI_ContentFrameHeader_l {
           clear: both;
           height: 50px;
           margin: 0;
           color: black;
           background: url(/images/NUI_box_l.png) no-repeat left top;
           border: solid 0px #BBC6D6;
           overflow: hidden;
           letter-spacing: 0;
           padding: 0 0 0 15px;
       }
   </style>
   ```

   will become:

   ```html
   <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"
                           href="http://www.example.com/style1.css" />
   <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"
                           href="http://www.example.com/style2.css" />
   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
       body {
           background: #FFF;
       }
       ..NUI_ContentFrameHeader_l {
           clear: both;
           height: 50px;
           margin: 0;
           color: black;
           background: url(/images/NUI_box_l.png) no-repeat left top;
           border: solid 0px #BBC6D6;
           overflow: hidden;
           letter-spacing: 0;
           padding: 0 0 0 15px;
       }
   </style>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Can an @import statement and other style statements co-exist inside a  tag?

Yes.

> If there are more than one @import statements in the beginning of a  tag and this is not a scoped style tag, can we convert @import statements to  statements and move them just above the  tag?

Yes.

It's considered [best practices](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) to convert `@import` statements to their own stylesheets due to `@import` blocking the file load - if they're loaded as separate sheets in their own `<style>` tags, they can be loaded in parallel by the browser.